# Setting up div tag content by calling the javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, html, button, tags

I have a div tag id="content", a button named "first lesson" and a function firstLesson() written in javascript.

Among other things, what I need to do is to make some code within a div tag visible by pressing the button "first lesson".

I know I have to use getElementById probably, but I can't get it to change the div tag content :/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML="hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it makes your life much simpler. You can do stuff like:

```
$('div#yourdiv').text('new content');
```

which changes the text of your div with `id` = `yourdiv` to the specified string.

Comment: thank you.javascript is still too much for me but im planing on learning jQuery eventually

Comment: @IWalkedAway: I recommend sooner rather than later. It will save you countless headaches (especially when dealing with multiple browser support)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I just found out about the InnerHTML :)

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML= ("<p>njanjanjanaj");
```

Comment: make sure to check for answers to your question before posting :)

Comment: sorry, it happened simultaneously